# Framer Motion - fade out element according to scroll position

Tags: reactjs, scroll, framer-motion, motion

Using [framer motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/), I am trying to fade in an object when it enters the viewport. Then I would like it to stay fixed for a while and eventually fade out.
So far I have only managed to fade the element in and fade it out when it leaves the viewport, which is too late. I was not able to figure out how to fix the element at a certain scroll position.

---

**Here is what I have achieved:** 
[image]

---

**This is what I am trying to achieve:**
[image]

---

**This is the Code Sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-dawn-q4figi?file=/src/App.js

Here is the code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [ref, inView] = useInView({
    threshold: 0.5,
    triggerOnce: false
  });

  const variants = {
    visible: { opacity: 1, scale: 1, y: 0 },
    hidden: {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 0.65,
      y: 50
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ height: 500 }} />
      <motion.div
        animate={inView ? "visible" : "hidden"}
        variants={variants}
        exit="hidden"
        transition={{ duration: 2, ease: "easeOut" }}
        className="box"
        ref={ref}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, just a couple of tweaks - mostly CSS for how you should position your animated element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.App {
  height: 300vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3b6fe0;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Here's a full demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sara-ce4pvx?file=/src/App.js

Note: it's a bit buggy to combine the `useInView` hook with the `scale` animation, as scaling the element will affect the in-view threshold. You could also consider [`use-scroll`](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-scroll/) as an alternative, it may be harder to implement but provide more control over the animation.